# I cant access the imported Database on Google Clould Platform - Access denied error message

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have created a new sql server(web & standard) instance on Google Clould platform.
Then imported my existing database on this instance.
I then connected my IDE(sql management studio) to this instance, but the problem is when I try to expand the import database I get access denied error message.
I'm accessing this Database via the default user 'sqlserver'

But I'm able to create new Databases with this user account. The issue is accessing the imported Databases.

Please assist.

[image]